# Align xml text having style property using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt; font-size:5">
    Washington
</P>
```

I have this code. I want to use the align the text washington to the center as suggested by the style using the XSLT.Currently I'm using this code to get the style values:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(catalog/cd/p/@style,'TEXT-ALIGN:'),';')"/>
```

It gives me the value text-align value i.e "center" but I want to use this property

Comment: Not clear to me, what are you trying to do with alignment? Are you trying to change the "center" value to "left", for example?

Comment: no m trying to set the property of text "Washington" to centre using XSTL 

and the P tag is in the XML format not in the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you asking how you set attributes in your output XML (which in your case will be HTML). Well, you could use the **xsl:attribute** element

```
<p>
   <xsl:attribute name="style">text-align:<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(catalog/cd/p/@style,'TEXT-ALIGN:'),';')"/></xsl:attribute>
</p>
```

This would output the following

```
<p style="text-align: center" />
```

However, the preferred method is to make us of attribute value templates, and so you could also code it like this (Note the use of curly braces {} to indicate the 'AVT')

```
<p style="text-align:{substring-before(substring-after(catalog/cd/p/@style,'TEXT-ALIGN:'),';')}">
```

So, for example, given the following input XML

```
<catalog>
   <cd>
      <p style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt; font-size:5">Washington</p>
   </cd>
</catalog>
```

If you use the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="p">
      <p style="text-align:{substring-before(substring-after(@style,'TEXT-ALIGN:'),';')}">
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </p>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following is output:

```
<p style="text-align: center">Washington</p>
```

Comment: Wooooww... amazing man great this is what exactly i want...cheerss.. :)

Comment: do u have idea to use this property with  flashx.textLayout.elements

Comment: I don't know flashx. That sounds like a whole new question you need to ask.

Comment: what if i need to change the output to 
<p align="centre">washington</p>

i use this  <p align="{substring-before(substring-after(@style,'TEXT-ALIGN:'),';')}">

and its not aligning the text to center

Comment: If the xslt is outputting <p align="center">washington</p> then the issue may be with your HTML or CSS.

Comment: there is no HTML or CSS as m trying it as a standalone there is just a XML and XSLT file as i mentioned in the ques...help me what to do